# Does anyone use AODL in a real application?

Tags: .net, odf

We are currently using the Excel interop API in .NET to generate simple spreadsheet documents from a template. So we load the template first, insert some rows, fill in some data (dates, text, and numbers), and make Excel visible so that the user can print or save the document we just generated.

But I'd like to get rid of the Excel dependency, and switch to the ODF format as well. Googling suggests AODL (C# libs for generating ODF docs) as the most obvious solution. But their last release is 1.3.0.0 BETA, and seems to be 3 years old. So I'm not sure if it's a good idea to depend on a potentially dead project... In that case, I'd need to find another solution. Any ideas? Or maybe someone could assure me that AODL is still alive?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are companies who still use that, and depend on it. AFAIK the AODL has not been updated to support latest ODT document changes, but up to OO 3.2 it works quite alright.

Latest AODL code is at [chrisc bitbucked](https://bitbucket.org/chrisc/aodl/overview). He has added support for SilverLight. This repo should be considered as the current official master repo. All other websites are not-used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of the spreadsheets you'd be just fine with AODL.

(I have contributed a bit to the project)

AODL is "old style C#" and takes a bit of time to get used to, but I have used it myself for production purposes.