# How do I install and use AODL?

Tags: c#, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I want to make a button that saves a libreoffice calc file. I've done some research on google and found a site to download AODL, but the download link doesn't work ([link](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/AODL)). I've downloaded AODL at another site: [sourcefourge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aodl/)

My question is: Have I downloaded the right file and how do I use it in my C# project?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 7):

From what I could find by doing some "research" (essentially googling around), AODL is not updated anymore.

*The following part is no longer viable/possible as the repository has been deleted/removed. If there are/were forks of this repository I do not know about them.*

According to [this, kind of old, SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10173183/937093) the newest version can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/chrisc/aodl/overview). The last commit to that repository happened in 2011. You could download the code from there and compile it (AODL is native C# code, so that shouldn't be a problem I guess).

I did some further "research" and found [this](http://www.opendocumentformat.org/developers/) uhm..."beauty". Be careful, it might give you eye cancer. If you scroll down a bit, you'll find a "C#" section. It lists the following libraries/projects:

- ODFtoolkit.org AODL (as mentioned before, this seems to be outdated)
- ODF.net (by Independendsoft. http://www.independentsoft.de/odf/)
- Aspose.Words and Aspose.Recognition (http://www.aspose.com/)
- GemBox.Spreadsheet (http://www.gemboxsoftware.com)
- XMLmind XSL-FO Converter (http://www.xmlmind.com/foconverter/)

I did extract those names/links from that website in case it goes down and to prevent anyone from having to look at those terrible colors. (Seriously, my eyes hurt now. Which could be related to it being late, but I like to think it's that website).